# Laravel 5 - Ajax POST - $request->all() returns empty array in PostController

Tags: ajax, laravel, http-post

Apologies for repeat but i've tried every suggestion to every question even vaguely similar to this to no end.

ajax post:

```
    var contactForm = $('#contactForm');
    contactForm.on('submit', (event) => {
        event.preventDefault()

        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN' : $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        })
        console.log(contactForm.serializeArray())
        $.ajax({
            dataType: "json",
            method : 'POST',
            url : 'contact-us/post',
            data : contactForm.serializeArray(),
            success: (res) => {
                console.log(res)
            }
        })
    })
```

Route handling post:

```
    Route::post('contact-us/post', 'EnquiryPostController@store');
```

PostController store method:

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        return response()->json(['success'=>$request->all()]);
    }
```

[Console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbPoK.jpg)

[response header from network tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlhGS.jpg)

[request header from network tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlTFb.jpg)

[from data from network tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KdvTI.jpg)

**UPDATE:**

Just to clarify:

- I am passing the CSRF token.
- The form inputs have name attributes.
- The PostController is receiving the POST request but simply does not contain any form data.
- This issue happens with AJAX POST and regular old form POST

Comment: Can you see in the request that the data is being send? the log you're showing is from console.log(contactForm.serializeArray())?

Comment: That is the {success: Array(0)} below right?

Comment: if you return any other value it like "success" => "hello", does it show it?

Comment: return response()->json(['success'=>"hello"]); returns {success: "hello"}

Comment: @JohnCroker remove dataType: "json" and add cache: false

Comment: Thanks but $request->all() still returns an empty array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this was not a Laravel issue but a Windows Server/web.config issue. I'd setup my site using the XML found [here](https://gist.github.com/jatubio/80dfc57fc18546706ec0). After much trial and error the issue was solved using this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <ModSecurity enabled="true" configFile="c:\inetpub\wwwroot\modsecurity.conf" />
        <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <clear />
                <add value="index.php" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="CanonicalHostNameRule1">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^dev\.financialservicesexpo\.co\.uk$" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="http://dev.financialservicesexpo.co.uk/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="default" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.php" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
        <staticContent>
            <clientCache cacheControlMaxAge="8.00:00:00" cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge"/>
        </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I wish I could explain why this fixed the issue but I have very little understanding of server configuration. If anyone would like to comment with insight I at least would find it interesting.

**IF THIS DID NOT HELP PLEASE READ BELOW**

Getting to the bottom of this issue involved trying a lot of different solutions found across even more questions posted to StackOverflow, etc. and was ultimately solved in two minutes after chatting to a colleague and working though the issue out loud. A frustrating lesson I keep needing to learn... So, in the hope this might help others the following is a list of the aforementioned solutions you should check.

- Check your form inputs have name attributes.
- Clear your browser cache.
- Clear Laravel cache data.
- Restart website
- When using AJAX try both serialize() and serializeArray()
- When using AJAX try submitting with different DataTypes and ContentTypes. The default should be fine but worth a shout if your doing something different.
- CSRF token: Add it via either a hidden input field or set in the request header. Only one should be needed.
- Make sure the /storage and /bootstrap folders have read/write privileges enabled.

If anyone has any suggestions or corrections to what I have written here please do speak up. I am no means a expert.

Answer (score 0):

Try in your ajax request using `type` instead of `method` like

```
    $.ajax({
            dataType: "json",
            type : 'POST',
            url : 'contact-us/post',
            data : contactForm.serializeArray(),
            success: (res) => {
                console.log(res)
            }
    })
```

Comment: Thanks but made no effect.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below solution to send data:

```
data : contactForm.serialize()
```

Comment: I have a amended the ajax but $request->all() still sends back an empty array. :(